# Windows 8.1 Robocopy Running on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, robocopy

I would like to copy the Robocopy.exe file from a Windows 8.1 system and run it on a Windows 7 PC. Both PC's are running the 64bit variant of their respective OS. Is this possible in any way?
At present I just get the error that it "is not a valid Win32 application".

The reason I wish to run it is because the newer version has the /J switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work. You can't run programs from a newer Windows version in an older Windows version. A you already noticed you get the `is not a valid Win32 application` error because the new exe is compiled for the higher Windows version (You can see this in Depends.exe under `OS Ver`).